# With c# extract a specific date pattern reliably from a long string

Tags: c#, asp.net

How does one reliably extract "20130901" each time - see code below? If there is a match I can then parse to a date. Its always in the format yyyyMMdd

```
            string s = "X23_CBW_13CP05AUGR1_20130901000000";
            Regex rg = new Regex("\\d+");
            Match m = rg.Match(s);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Always yyyyMMdd, but what about the rest of the string? Can the date pattern appear anywhere or just at the end?

Comment: does it always follow the last underscore _ ?

Comment: I want to avoid relying on 3rd underscore and things like that. I need it to start from left and find 8 consecutive numbers between 0-9 then return the 8 char string as 20130901

Comment: This way its re-useable for many file names

Comment: yyyyMMdd can appear anywhere but the yyyyMMdd will never repeat but there are 00000s

Comment: I would point out that in your example, if the third underscore were removed, pulling the first 8 character numeric sequence would result in an invalid date 1201-30-90. Do you want to get advanced and extract the first 8 characters that form a valid date?

Comment: Should have to check long ints having length 8 and of pattern [4dig][1-12][1-31]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regular expression to only pull out 8 digit numeric sequences and then `ParseExact` the first match:

```
string s = "X23_CBW_13CP05AUGR1_20130901000000";
Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{8}");
Match m = rg.Match(s);


if (m.Success)
{
    DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(m.Value, "yyyyMMdd",
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // ... 
    // Do something with your value here
}
```

**Advanced Implementation** aka Overkill

If you need the engine to find the first valid date string, even if there are other long number sequences before it, you could implement:

```
string s = "X23CBW13992238455222348CP05AUGR120130901000000";
Regex rg = new Regex(@"\d{8,}");
MatchCollection mc = rg.Matches(s);

DateTime? d = null;


foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    string digits = m.Value;

    for (int n = 0; n < digits.Length - 8; n++)
    {
        try
        {
            d = DateTime.ParseExact(digits.Substring(n, 8), "yyyyMMdd",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            break;
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    if (d != null)
        break;
}


if (d != null)
{
// Use your value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring for this

```
     string ans;

     string input="X23_CBW_13CP05AUGR1_20130901000000";

        int index = input.LastIndexOf("_");
        ans = input.Substring(index+1,8);

        Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", ans);
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I assume you have your date always after the last '_' symbol and the date format will always be yyyyMMdd

Comment: Very simple but not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern,

```
/\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])/g
```